# Exchange 2013 OWA empty calendar

Tags: exchange, outlook-web-app

We're in the process of moving an Exchange 2013 installation to another server as we have outgrown the old one. The new servers has been set up and all mailboxes have been migrated successfully onto the new machine and everyone can log in and read their mails, nothing wrong with that.

When going into the calendar page on OWA, however, things get a bit tricky. When using the 'full' version of OWA, appointments just do not show up. Instead, a little error-icon pops up saying that one or more calendars could not be loaded, even though everything has been moved successfully. Logging in to the 'Light' version of OWA, appointments show up without error, even when unmounting the old database, or turning off the old server.

So, to recap - appointments do not show up in full OWA, claiming that 'one or more calendars could not be loaded', even though the light version of OWA has no problems doing just that.

Are we going nuts? Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Does the issue occur in Firefox/ Chrome?

Comment: The issue occurs in IE, Chrome and Safari. I dont know about Firefox. When monitoring xmlhttp requests, appointments do get fetched successfully from the server. Could it be a bug?

Comment: Not enough info to know if its a bug or not at this stage. As a quick test to eliminate mailbox related issue, create a brand new user and see if it works?

Comment: Doesn't work with old nor new users.